# How to use RazorEngine to include files?

Tags: c#, razorengine

I am trying to use RazorEngine to include other files in a template, but I am a little stuck. I got the basics working, but I want to be able to use `@Include("somefile.html")` in my template.

This is what I got until now:

```
string tpl = @"@Include(""foo.html"");";

ResolvePathTemplateManager r = new ResolvePathTemplateManager(new string[] { "html" });
var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
config.TemplateManager = r;
var service = RazorEngineService.Create(config);

var a = service.RunCompile(tpl, "name", null, new { test = "TEMPLATE" });
```

The current working directory has a `html` dir where `foo.html` is located, yet I get this error:

> Could not resolve template name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperently, when resolving paths, you cannot use a string-template. This code works:

```
ResolvePathTemplateManager r = new ResolvePathTemplateManager(new string[] { "html" });
var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
config.TemplateManager = r;
var service = RazorEngineService.Create(config);

var a = service.RunCompile("foo.html");
```

and in `foo.html` I can use:

```
@Include("otherfile.html");
```

to include a file from the same dir.

Comment: FWIW, We use a `DelegateTemplateManager` which allows you to pass a function that takes a single `string` argument instead of a `ResolvePathTemplateManager`.  Within that function you can then do whatever you want to resolve the template - we have an array of paths we search through etc.  Whether _that_ works with string templates or not...